# Properly catching syntax errors with coroutines in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a little Python script that basically runs two things in parallel. I'm coming from JavaScript and trying to use Python's async/await coroutine features, but I'm having a little trouble getting it to work as I expect.

It was easy enough to get a first two functions running in parallel. The problems I'm running into are relating to catching syntax errors.

Specifically, I was trying to add some math to one of my functions but Python would just seem to hang on that step (prints before worked, after they did not). I traced my issues down to the syntax exception not bubbling up as I expect, specifically that the asyncio seems to hide errors if they happen inside "futures". I think this is where my problem lies but I've had a heck of a time trying to catch the errors as I expect.

I tried wrapping the whole offending coroutine in a `try`/`except` but that seemed to break my other coroutines (seemingly breaking my assumptions about how coroutines work).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

async def other():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('foobar')
        
async def test():
    try:
        while True:
            a = undefinedVariable
    except:
        print("Why doesn't this always catch??")

# catches as expected
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([test()]))

# doesn't catch, fills screen with "foobar" lines, once a second, runs forever
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([test(), other()]))

# Trying other things...
# Error:
# RuntimeError: no running event loop
# sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited"
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([asyncio.create_task(t()) for t in [test, other]]))
```

Running a single problematic coroutine works as expected.

Combining it with another coroutine that doesn't error makes the other coroutine stop respecting the `asyncio.sleep`.

I once got to a point where if I hit Ctrl+C, it would stop printing "foobar", print the syntax error, and then exit, but I failed to capture that code and it's lost to undoes.

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ooops! Well, that explains the runaway loop in my sample. Doesn't explain the rest of my issue (which happens with `await`). Code sample updated.

Comment: I'm trying to get `"Why doesn't this always catch??"` to print once and then take down the rest of the execution. As it stands, I wasn't figured out how to make it stop the `other()` task. More other poking seems to have gotten me an answer that works, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference in the docs that `asyncio.run()` should be used as the "main" entry point and handles all the loop creation and cleanup, so I tried it.

Using that was a little more clear than the event loop stuff. The following does what I want.

```py
asyncio.run(asyncio.wait([test(), other()], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED))
```

What I don't understand is why when I tried `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` earlier it kept running. Maybe there was some other typo that I missed.

One source of confusion was that coroutines do not run unless something is awaiting them.

Not sure if this helps someone else in the future. Thanks to everyone that looked.